# default Copy constructer and default assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, copy-constructor

what is the difference between either of these used in a code as i have used [here](http://ideone.com/bEYxo).(line 44 ad line 45 both work fine)

Excerpt:

```
Date temp = *this;  //ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR CALL(PROVIDED BY COMPILER)
//Date temp(*this); //COPY CONSTRUCTOR CALL(PROVIDED BY COMPILER)
```

**My Opinion** : Is it that during assignment like object1 = object2; contents of object2 are deleted and placed in object1 while while if the same thing happens via a copy constructor contents of object2 still remain( i mean just as the word suggests "copy").

NOTE: By the way my code compiled fine in Microsoft visual C++ 2008 but it gave a  warning

```
  prog.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Date&)’:
  prog.cpp:103: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to
```

in ideone.com.Any reasons for that.

Comment: the warning is self evident - you are attempting to store a `const char*` in a `char*` (well array of them - but you should understand by now that string literals are const)

Comment: thanks I get that now but MV C++ does not gives any warning is the compiler helping me with that

Comment: operator= is never called in your excerpt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date temp = *this; 
Date temp(*this);
```

Both call copy constructor,
First is called as **Copy Initialization** & second is called as **Direct Initialization**.

Simple Rule to remember this is:
If an object is getting created as well as initialized in the same statement then it calls Copy constructor.

If an object is just assigned and not being created in the same statement then it calls Assignment(Copy Assignment) operator.

---

The compiler complains because:

An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char”. And implicit conversion from const to non-const qualification for string literals (4.2) is deprecated.

References:
**C++ Standard Section [2.13.4/2]:**
*An ordinary string literal has type `array of n const char`, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has static storage duration (3.7) and is initialized with the given characters.*

**Annexure D section [D.4/1]**
*The implicit conversion from `const` to `non-const` qualification for `string literals` (4.2) is deprecated.*

So to avoid the warning You should use:

```
static const char *monthName[13]
      ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: so L"hello" is not MS extension but c++ standard?

Comment: +1: A little known difference between `Data x = y;` and `Data x(y);` (which both indeed call a constructor and not the assignment operator): the latter also works if the constructor is marked `explicit`, the former doesn't.

Comment: @Ali Veli: L"Hello" is windows version of Unicode string. The OP is talking about **String Literals**, Please look up the bold words on google and I am sure it will make more sense, If you don't understand, Do ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

```
static char *monthName[13]
```

can/should be

```
static const char *monthName[13]
```

to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the default copy constructor and the default assignment operator is that when the assignment operator is called, the members of the receiving object are already initialized with values, and you are simply replacing them with copies of the values in the second object.  With the copy constructor, the members are initialized as copies of the members in the second object.  The second object should be completely unaffected by either operation.

However, you are not using the assignment operator in your code, you are using the copy constructor.  If you had done this:

```
Date temp;
temp = *this;
```

Then you would be using the assignment operator.